# nginx - fastcgi_read_timeout, what is the best value?

Tags: php, nginx, timeout, fastcgi, nginx-config

We're using Nginx as a proxy for our PHP application, we have an API that takes more than 120s to be completed, so we're going to increase our Nginx timeout.

What is the recommended value for fastcgi_read_timeout? and is there any security issues, vulnerabilities or threats we may have if we increase the timeout to a very long time?

Answer (score 1):

There is no recommended value for the timeout. I would set a value that fits and monitor for 504 errors.

If you expect to receive multiple API calls at the same time, you'll quickly run into other issues (and limits), so maybe your API should (for example) return a task_id and let the consumer poll the task status.